# RDB by master and AOF by replicas

Tags: redis, persistence, replication, redis-rdb

How can we configure the REDIS in such way that the master create.manage the RDB file and the replicas can create/manage the AOF file. This could shift the burden from the master to replicas to create/manage both the files/database.

Answer (score 0):

Just set rdb in the master conf file (save) and set aof in the replica conf file (appendonly).

Then it works the way you want.

Comment: What is the solution if they are not static, but dynamic. The master and slave are decided dynamically. There is just one config file. Is there an option in conf file which could be used for slave/master configurations.